# \thispagestyle{empty} has no effect with pages with figures

Tags: header-footer

this is my code:

```
\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{figure}
\centerline{\includegraphics[scale=0.7]{alciatus2.pdf}}
\caption{\textit{Alciati Emblematum liber}, Emblema CXLV, In Senatum boni Principis (1531), D1v}
\end{figure}
```

it's part of a double sided book.

Comment: Place the line *inside* the `figure` environment. And btw, use `\centering` instead of `centerline`.

Comment: Excellent, now I've got the same problem after a list of abbreviations. I get a header on a blank page. What should I do?

Comment: @Johannes_B  I've tried and it doesn't work.